# Web standard to open link in existing open tab

Tags: javascript, html

On a desktop, if I have application A open and then in application B, click on a link to application A, it does not usually open a new application, instead the link opening is handled by the existing open instance of application A.  Is this possible for a website?  i.e. is there a way for a website domain to tell the browser that when a page to that website domain A is open in one of the browser's tabs, that a user's click on a link for that domain A from a different application or tab and domain, can be handled by the open tab for domain A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, but it's in development as [a PWA capability](https://web.dev/url-protocol-handler/) based on [`Navigator.registerProtocolHandler()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler). You can implement something close to this behavior now using service workers and [`WindowClient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowClient).